# Fetch result SQL query data to Table JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I want to make jtable display my result data from SQL query , the code like this

```
private void TampilTabel(){
    String header[] = {"No","Nama","TTL","Usia"};
    DefaultTableModel tabelku = new DefaultTableModel(null, header);
    Object obj[] = new Object[10];

     jTable1.setModel(tabelku);
     TableColumnModel columnModel = jTable1.getColumnModel();
     jTable1.setRowHeight(35);

    try{
        stat = (Statement) koneksiMySQL.GetConnection().createStatement();
        String sql = "select No_Induk, Nama, Tgl_Lahir, \n" +
                     "(YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(Tgl_Lahir)) - (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(`Tgl_Lahir`,5))\n" +
                     "AS Umur\n" +
                     "FROM tabel_pegawai ORDER BY Nama";
        rst = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rst.next()){

                    obj[0] = rst.getString("No_Induk");
                    obj[1] = rst.getString("Nama");
                    obj[2] = rst.getString("Tgl_Lahir");
                    obj[3] = rst.getString("No_Induk");
                    tabelku.addRow(obj);
        }

        rst.close();


    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Data Tidak Ada");
    }
}
```

Question is how to get result data without use getString(), because in my database i didnt have 'Umur' row

Thanks before

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRddE.png]

Comment: As far as I can see, `Umur` is a column alias and as such is a part of your ResultSet.  So what exactly seems to be a problem?

Comment: `how to get result data without use getString(),` - use getObject()? I really don't understand the question so it is just a wild guess.

Comment: the problem is i cant display 'umur' on jtable , if i can i always got error message. So how to display alias column on jtable

Comment: @camickr getObject() what ? what i write on bracket ?

Comment: (1-) `i always got error message.` - and we are not mind readers. We don't know what error message you are getting.

Comment: BTW why do you have `\n` in your query?

Comment: for new line @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you want to do

```
 obj[3] = rst.getString("Umur");
```

or you could simply do by column number

```
obj[3] = rst.getString(4);
```

Comment: yeah i did wrong when i insert data to DB, thats way usefull